# Can't download mix on Mix Radio, how to clean cache?

Tags: apps, windows-10-mobile, mixradio

Recently I downloaded one mix, apparently something went wrong and from that moment on I can’t save mixes.

What happens is:

I download the mix, it reaches 100% normally, but I can’t open (remains on the black loading screen forever)

If I restart the app and go to the offline mixes the mix is greyed out and says download failed, sometimes another duplicate appears..

What can I do?

I already tried to reinstall the app…
Is there any way to clean the App cache?

Comment: Are you using Windows 8.1 or Windows 10?

Comment: Windows 10 Mobile

Comment: Well, not being able to download MixRadio is not the only problem you have: http://thenextweb.com/apps/2016/02/16/mixradio-is-shutting-down-just-a-year-after-being-acquired-by-line/

Comment: Oh crap.. Microsoft should have never sold, it was a really good app...

Comment: Should I delete this question? I emailed them and they are answering..

Comment: @miguelmnp Don't delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that Mix Radio is now closed down.

But don't worry, there are other options available for you:

1. Spotify

Spotify has a great music app and offer a subscription based service called Spotify Premium.

2. Pandora Music

Pandora Music is a popular music streaming app, it too, offers a subscription based service.

3. MTV Trax

MTV Trax is a brand new music streaming app which allows you to download all tracks to your device as long as you are subscribed to their subscription-based service.

Comment: You are right, and you also have Deezer, my question was asked before the announcement that MixRadio would be closed..
Sadly we don't have any other software that can predict songs you like based on 2 or 3 songs pre selected. MixRadio was really great on this :)